# How to store xml data into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a xml format data which is came from server. Now i want to store it into database and it should load on button click. How should i do this?

```
enter code here
```

```
<qst_code>    7    </qst_code>
<qst_prg_code>    1     </qst_prg_code>
<qst_mod_code>    2   </qst_mod_code>







<qst_Question>What is not true about left dominant cardiology circulation?  </qst_Question>



<qst_opt1>It is seen in 20% of the population</qst_opt1>
<qst_opt2>Left circumflex artery supplies the Posterior descending artery</qst_opt2>
<qst_opt3>Left circumflex artery terminates as obtuse marginal branch</qst_opt3>
<qst_opt4>Left circumflex artery may originate from right coronary sinus</qst_opt4>
<qst_opt01>1</qst_opt01>
<qst_opt02>1</qst_opt02>
<qst_opt03>1</qst_opt03>



<qst_opt04>1</qst_opt04>
<qst_CorctOpt>1</qst_CorctOpt>
<qst_Marks>10</qst_Marks>
<qst_company_code>1</qst_company_code>
<user_code>1</user_code>
```

Comment: XML keeps data in a tree. SQLite keeps data in tables. There are many ways to translate between a tree and a table; I can't help you choose the best way because I have no idea what that data looks like or what you're doing with it. You'll have to provide some more information.

Comment: thanks mike  i am providing the xml data  structure

Answer (score 3):

One option is to store it as a string if the data is not too large, else break it into a schema that maps to sqlite and recreate it while loading.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML data is large, I would rather change the data exchange type to json. XML parsing and then insert is a very expensive operation and is time-consuming.

Some issues which you will face with XML parsing and insert.

a. XML parsing is memory intensive and so you heap size will grow, you need to keep an eye on this as this might cause crash.
b. Inserts in SQLite DB will take around ~100ms per tuple (row), so you can calculate the time it will required to pump in thousands of rows of data.

If you data is not too large don't bother about using SQLite.